# Creating a line break while outputting a string multiple times in python

Tags: python, string, output, repeat

Here is the code snippet.

I am attempting to have a user input their name and age to output what year they will turn 100.

I then ask the user for a number and want to repeat the string x times.

When I try to use a line break '\n' I get an unexpected character error. Unsure of where I should go with this.

```
name = input ("What is your name: ")
age = input("what is your age: ")
age = int(age)
howLong = (100 - age) + 2021 #calculates the year
times = input("Pick a number: ")# asks user for a year
print(int(times) * (name+" will be 100 years old in: " + str(howLong))) #tells what year it will be
```

I have tried

```
print(int(times) * ('name+" will be 100 years old in: " + str(howLong))\n') #tells what year it will be
```

Also

```
print(int(times) * (name+" will be 100 years old in: " + str(howLong))'\n') #tells what year it will be
```

Also

```
print(int(times) * (name+" will be 100 years old in: " + str(howLong))\n) #tells what year it will be
```

Also

```
print(int(times) * ('''name+" will be 100 years old in: " + str(howLong))'''\n) #tells what year it will be
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any pointers? Yes this is homework, this part was a bonus. Trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The new line character needs to be in a string literal and then can be appended to the rest of the string.

```
print(int(times) * (name + " will be 100 years old in: " + str(howLong) + '\n'))
```